# How do I use a UITabBarController using the same ViewController for every tab?

Tags: ios, objective-c

and change the content and title of the ViewController depending on which tab is selected.

Is it possible?

Below is what I tried within my UITabBarController's viewDidLoad function

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSMutableArray * tabs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    EventsViewController * upcomingEvents = (EventsViewController *)[[self viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
    upcomingEvents.title = @"Upcoming Events";
    upcomingEvents.events = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"]];

    [tabs addObject:upcomingEvents];

    EventsViewController * myEvents = (EventsViewController *)[[self viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];
    myEvents.title = @"My Events";
    myEvents.events = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyEvents" ofType:@"plist"]];

    [tabs addObject:myEvents];

    [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:tabs animated:YES];

}
```

This results in the error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setEvents:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x108fe3b50'
```

My current storyboard setup
[image: My setup]

EDIT:

In the end with some help and understand from Unkn0wn.Bit.

I scrapped the custom UITabBarController and just adjusted my viewWillAppear function in my EventsViewController (UITableViewController) to change the source depending on the selectedIndex of the tabBarController.

Effectively using the same view (with different information) for multiple tabBar buttons using two separate NSMutableArrays (myEvents, upcomingEvents).

```
(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if([self.tabBarController selectedIndex]) {
        self.events = self.myEvents;
        self.navBar.title = @"My Events";
    } else {
        //temporary instead run function that either downloads events or tries to update if necessary
        self.events = self.upcomingEvents;
        self.navBar.title = @"Upcoming Events";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, instantiate multiple times. What did you try? What didn't work? Show code.

Comment: I found that this is not particularly reliable, at least on iOS 8. The state of the selectedIndex does not update at the right time for consistent detection.

Comment: I found that it's VERY reliable if you put the logic in viewDidLoad instead...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use interface builder, In your story board file create multiple view controllers ( ctrl+drag from your Tab Bar Controller to assign them to tabs ) design your view as you wish, but set their custom class to one same class !

Comment: This doesn't actually seem to relate to the problem described by the error message.

Comment: I was also thinking that as a solution but I figured there must be a way to do it without extra view controllers.

Comment: I answered to the question that was in question title. The code tells something else. My solution was to not use the code in `viewDidLoad` and instead, use that mechanism to make your tab bar controller work !

Comment: If you don't use multiple controllers it would be a little harder to organize your views. That's a safe and clean choice !

Comment: With extra view controllers but using the same custom class, how do I identify which view I'm using so I know what data source the class should load?

How do I uniquely identify the storyboard or view?

Comment: You can check to see which of your tab bar items is currently selected! I guess the code is something like : `[self.myTabBarController selectedIndex]`
You can instantiate your storyboard when your app launches, and then monitor where you go from root view controller using segues and identifiers.

Answer (score 3):

This part of the error message:

> -[UINavigationController setEvents:]

tells you that you are calling `setEvents:` on an instance of `UINavigationController` and it doesn't respond.

Your issue is that you are forgetting your view controller hierarchy because you have your `EventsViewController` instances inside navigation controllers so you need to traverse the hierarchy to call the correct instances.

i.e.:

```
UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)[[self viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
EventsViewController *upcomingEvents = [navController topViewController];
```

Comment: Can you provide and example of traversing the hierarchy to reach the EventsViewController?

Answer (score 1):

You could use multiple instances of your `ViewController` subclass, and that would give you what you want. But if you wanted to simply use the exact same instance for each, then you would want to use a `UITabBar` directly, not a `UITabBarController`. You could add the `UITabBar` to your `UIViewController` subclass and implement the `UITabBarDelegate` protocol.